# How to use an image to control the displace modifier?

Tags: modeling, uv, displacement

I have a simple rectangle which I have subdivided multiple times, added UV for colors and then added Displace modifier.

[image]

For the displace texture I've set a black and white version of the image used for the material.

[image]

Now the problem is when I set strength to some value to see the result, this is what i see (I set it more than I need but just so details are easier to see):

[image]

As you can see first problem is that it started displacing on top of the object. I know i can handle this with `Direction` but the Displacement image on that part is painted black (so it should stay down).

Second problem is that as I can see it doesn't even follow Texture i have assigned. As you can see on the image, it has wide displacement from top to the bottom all the way, and it is not like that in texture!

So what is the solution? What am i doing wrong?

I have done this in Blender Render but i would like to do it in Cycles also (which i know how to do on flat surface)

Comment: First, check if scale of the object is applied (Object mode > Ctrl+A). Then your Displace modifier doesn't in any way use UV map of the object for now, to make it use it choose Texture Coordinates > UV.

Comment: Yap. It was Texture Coordinates..... Thank you very much.

Comment: @MrZak One more question, it go little over top and sides (where it should not be) displace. How i can fix that? [IMAGE](http://prntscr.com/j6o3py)

Comment: you can set the displacement to occur in some [vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html?highlight=vertex%20groups) (and exclude the vertex that are not part of such group)

Comment: It may be better in your case to choose a direction for displacement instead of "normal", like maybe the y axis. That seems more like what you want than using vertex groups, although both could achieve the desired result.

Comment: It's hard to tell from textured image only, you might want to edit the question with more screenshots of UV map and image mapping shown. If you really want sides and top parts to be displaced as well then make sure image is mapped as expected, i.e. there aren't any black or white seams around places where artifacts are visible. Easier way is to skip displace on the sides using vertex groups as is already suggested